# Oracle for Update SKIP LOCKED and Left Join

Tags: oracle, skip, locked

In the moment I'm working on a DB migration and I need to migrate the query below from Sybase to Oracle, but I really don't know how to "translate" the 3 READPAST.
Could anyone help me pls?

```
SELECT CC.COURS_CLIENT_ID
       , CC.TYPE_CLIENT
       , ISNULL( RT1.CODE , RV.CODE) AS CODE 
FROM TB_CLIENT CC READPAST
       LEFT JOIN TB_TRANSCO RT1 READPAST 
           ON CC.INST_ID = RT1.CONTRAT_ID AND RT1.TRANSCO_ID = 111
       LEFT JOIN TB_VAL RV READPAST
            ON CC.INST_ID = RV.VAL_ID AND RV.TRANSCO_ID = 111
       LEFT JOIN TB_CONT RC 
           ON RC.CONTRIB_ID = CC.CONTRIB_ID
WHERE CC.TRT_ID = 123 
AND CC.STATUT = 'STD'
ORDER BY CC.COURS_CLIENT_ID,RT1.CRE_DT
```

Comment: are you using the select to retrieve rows or as part of a `select for update` ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the definiton of Sybase

> **readpast** allows delete commands on data-only-locked tables to proceed
> without being blocked by incompatible locks held by other tasks. On
> datarows-locked tables, readpast skips all rows on which shared,
> update, or exclusive locks are held by another task.
>
> On datapages-locked tables, readpast skips all pages on which shared,
> update, or exclusive locks are held by another task.

In your case, if the select is being execute for update some records, you can use `select for update` with the option `skip locked`

```
SELECT CC.COURS_CLIENT_ID, CC.TYPE_CLIENT, ISNULL( RT1.CODE , RV.CODE) AS CODE FROM TB_CLIENT CC 
       LEFT JOIN TB_TRANSCO RT1 ON CC.INST_ID = RT1.CONTRAT_ID AND RT1.TRANSCO_ID = 111
       LEFT JOIN TB_VAL RV ON CC.INST_ID = RV.VAL_ID AND RV.TRANSCO_ID = 111
       LEFT JOIN TB_CONT RC ON RC.CONTRIB_ID = CC.CONTRIB_ID
            WHERE CC.TRT_ID = 123 AND CC.STATUT = 'STD'
           FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
```

However, the select for update skipped locked is useful in high concurrency environments to prevent locking errors, but you run the risk of logical corruption where a changed value is dependent upon another column value within the row. In general, the re-read strategy is better, where you re-read each row before update in to ensure that it did not change since the initial read.

Comment: Thank you @Roberto Hernandez, but I'm not sure if that approach will be same thing because we have 3 READPAST on the query. I'm trying to use cursor to loop through the values which is quite simple with where and inner joins statements, but using left ones is not so simple.

Comment: The `READPAST` allows you to have dirty reads in Sybase. Oracle does not allow dirty reads. If you are updating, Oracle will use the SCN of the rows in the moment you start the query. That means when you start the query for update, the select will retrieve the rows that at that very same moment are commited

Comment: If you are using  a procedure in Oracle, you can post the code.